# flexible div height between flexible height header and footer div's

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I want to achieve same thing horizontally as you can **[see here](http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/YL4f3/)** vertically and `IE9+` compatible

**[Edit]:** I would like to have middle content on overflow have scroll bar, in this case tabling won't help.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/YL4f3/)**

Css:

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: silver;
}

.top{
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}

.bottom{
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    background-color: green;
}

.middle{
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
</div>
```

---

### Question: Is it possible without javascript and any fixed values?

I don't want to do something like this:

```
.top-div {
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.middle-div{
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.bottom-div{
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

In this scenario I'm forced to use JavaScript if I want to change height of footer or header.

Answer (score 0):

using calc from css3

the style:

```
body,html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: silver;
}
.container,.top, .bottom, .middle{
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.top{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

.bottom{
    height: 50%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
}

.middle{
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-height: calc(100%  -  100px);
    -moz-height: calc(100%  -  100px);
    height: calc(100%  -  100px);
}
```

the markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YL4f3/1/

Comment: Sorry this isn't really I'm looking for as I stated before I want to avoid fixed height situation. As you can see by yourself changing values will increase overall container height thus overflowing view-port and at same time footer going out. The example I've given fills the container and doesn't overflow until maximum container width reached by either of sides.

Comment: I think if you just change .bottom { height: 50%;  to   50px;  you should overflow fine.

Answer (score 0):

For now you have to give height to your containers. Once you have the content in place, just change the height to auto.

Also, when you change the height to auto, change the margin-top for the middle div as per your page needs.

```
<style>
.container div{
    float:left; }
  .container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: silver;
}

.top{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    background-color: red;
}

.bottom{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: green;
}

.middle{
    margin-top:100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 1000px;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Everything would be ok if didn't need to change `.middle` values. As I stated in my question, I don't want to have fixed values for middle.

Comment: The height i have added is just for sake of testing. Want you add your content remove the height or make height auto. For testing I had to give height or browser would make it hide since it doesn't have any content in it.